# need to write json dataframe into avro file format from spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

hi i have to read json data to spark DF and after that i need to write that DF in avro file format from spark shell, am getting following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: Please share representative code that illustrates your issue. Generic examples work, as long as they result in the issue you have a question about.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the spark-avro library?

You can do that when starting the spark-shell as follows:

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.6
```

Answer (score 1):

`spark-avro` external library, You have to import `spark-avro` package into `spark-shell`.

Check below

```
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0
```